# Sections of endomorphisms of a vector bundle

Tags: vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

The following could be rather silly question but I haven'd found it stated explicitly; from the other side, it seems to me, that this fact is used often without comments.

The problem is the following: consider vector bundle $S \to M$ and construct the endomorphism vector bundle $End(S) \to M$ where

$$(End(S))_x:=End(S_x).$$

Now take $\Gamma(M,End(S))$ to be the module (over $C(M)$) of continuous sections. Is is true that this module coincides with $End_{C(M)}(\Gamma(M,S))$?

Comment: I think it's true but it's not silly. You'd have to use bump functions to show that elements of $End_{C(M)}(\Gamma(M,S))$ act on sections locally, i.e. value at a point depends only on the value of the section at that point.